# Using static C++ library from within go-code using SWIG

Tags: c++, go, static-libraries, swig, static-linking

How can I use C++-code that uses static C++-libraries from within a [go](https://go.dev/) file using [SWIG](https://www.swig.org/) (Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator)?

*(Note: The following post already describes the answer and a working solution)*

I am using SWIG to implement the bridge in-between my C++-code and my go-file. The C++-code resides in a .cpp-file, which in turn calls a method from a static .a C++-library that I created.

The question is, how to set up all parts appropriately in order to call a method from the static library from my go code.

This is my trivial setup:

**Simple.cpp**

```
#include "Simple.h"

int DoSimple()
{
    return 1701;
}
```

**Simple.h**

```
int DoSimple();
```

**Foo.cpp**

```
#include "include/Foo.h"

int foo()
{
    return DoSimple();
}
```

**Foo.h**

```
#include "d:\\home\\workspaces\\simple\\include\\Simple.h"

int foo();
```

**swig.i**

```
%module simple

%{
#include "include/Foo.h"
%}

%include "include/Foo.h"
```

**main.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "awesomeProject/foo"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello")

    a := simple.Foo()

    fmt.Println(a)

    fmt.Println("Bye")
}
```

I am creating the static and shared libraries out of these two files as so:

```
$ g++ -c -o Simple.o Simple.cpp -Id:/home/workspaces/simple/include
$ g++ -shared -o libSimple.so Simple.o
$ ar rcs libSimple.a Simple.o
```

I am then ending up having:

```
|-- simple/
       |-- include/
       |    |-- Simple.h
       |-- libSimple.a
       |-- libSimple.so
       |-- Simple.cpp
       |-- Simple.o


|-- foo/
      |-- main/
      |    |-- main.go
      |-- swig/
      |    |-- include/
      |           |-- Foo.h
      |    |-- Foo.cpp
      |    |-- simple.go
      |    |-- swig.i
      |    |-- swig_wrap.cxx
```

The two relevant go environment variables are set to:

```
$ go env -w CGO_LDFLAGS="-Ld:/home/workspaces/simple -lSimple"
$ go env -w CGO_CXXFLAGS=-Id:/home/workspaces/simple/include
```

Finally, I am issuing:

```
$ swig -go -c++ -intgosize 64 ../foo/swig.i
$ go build -x .\main.go
```

And surprise, surprise, the output is

```
$ go run main.go
Hello
1701
Bye
```

So, all good.